# Failed to create MSSQL login for virtual account

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, iis

I have ***Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0  (Build 19044: ) (Hypervisor)***

Running under default account: NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

Also I have virtual account: IIS APPPOOL\myService.
It has local profile in control panel->system->system properties->User profiles

If I try to create MSSQL login and do it under Windows credentials - it fails

```
 DECLARE @SfsLoginName sysname = N'IIS APPPOOL\SecurityFrameworkService';
 EXECUTE(N'CREATE LOGIN [' + @SfsLoginName + N'] FROM WINDOWS')
```

Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
**Windows NT user or group 'IIS APPPOOL\SecurityFrameworkService' not found. Check the name again.**

If I use real windows user:  MACHINENAME\realuser  - it works

If I use sa authentication I can create sql login for virtual account.

What can I do for this situation?  I want to change it without changing MSSQL account to admin.

Comment: Why don't you just create a real account and run your app pool under that identity, then add that account into SQL Server.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.